# ROWTYPE in CURSOR postgresql

Tags: postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

i want to know if it is possible to get "Rowtype" for a cursor in postgresql (pl/pgsql).
..

my cursor has a select from multiple table and i don't know how to    get the rowtype.

```
c_Data CURSOR FOR 
select 
 dst_description 
, cnt_number 
, prd_name 
, grt_code 
, res_currency 
, res_date 
, prm_installmentdate 

from tbl_xxx, tbl_yyy, tbl_aaa
where cnt_id = res_xxx
and prd_id = cnt_yyy
and dst_id = prd_aaa
and grt_id = res_xxx
and prm_id = res_aaa; 

l_Data c_Data%rowtype;
```

please help

Comment: Why do you think you need that?

Comment: you don't need rowtype. Use RECORD type instead.

Answer (score 1):

More like this way round.

```
declare 
l_data record; 

begin
select 
INTO l_data --<<
 dst_description 
, cnt_number 
, prd_name 
, grt_code 
, res_currency 
, res_date 
, prm_installmentdate 
from tbl_xxx, tbl_yyy, tbl_aaa
where cnt_id = res_xxx
and prd_id = cnt_yyy
and dst_id = prd_aaa
and grt_id = res_xxx
and prm_id = res_aaa;
```

l_data will then be of the rowtype you need.